# $NODE_PATH for NVM version of NODE not working

Tags: node.js, nvm

`which node` on the CLI correctly points to the NVM version.

```
which node  
/me/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/node
```

In `.zshrc` I attempt to use `which node` to point to the NVM version of Node.
    export NODE_PATH=`which node`

source it..
`source ~/.zshrc`

Which Node I am using?

```
which node     
me/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/node
```

The correct one..

Now, echoing the $NODE_PATH..

```
echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Wrong one..

Comment: `RUN export NODE_PATH=$(which node);echo $NODE_PATH;`

Comment: Put `export NODE_PATH=$(which node);echo $NODE_PATH;` in `.zshrc`. Outputs `/usr/local/bin/node`. Not sure why `which node` would spit out differently values in `.zshrc` than on the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

`NODE_PATH` is an environment variable that allows you to `require` modules from a non-standard location; it should not be a pointer to a `node` binary.

In other words, you should `unset NODE_PATH`, always.